# NHibernate and MySQL Nullable object must have a value

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I'm having a problem that I would appreciate some guidance on where to start on. Let me first set the scene.

I've recently migrated from SQL Server to MySQl database, all integration tests passed against SQL Server now one is failing since the migration with this exception:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not execute query
[ select post0_.Id as Id1_, post0_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_, post0_.Title as Title1_, post0_.Body as Body1_, post0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy1_, post0_.ParentId as ParentId1_ from Posts post0_, Users user1_ where post0_.CreatedBy=user1_.Id and ((user1_.Username is null) and (? is null) or user1_.Username=?) and (post0_.ParentId is null) order by post0_.CreatedAt desc ]
  Name:p1 - Value:username1
[SQL: select post0_.Id as Id1_, post0_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_, post0_.Title as Title1_, post0_.Body as Body1_, post0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy1_, post0_.ParentId as ParentId1_ from Posts post0_, Users user1_ where post0_.CreatedBy=user1_.Id and ((user1_.Username is null) and (? is null) or user1_.Username=?) and (post0_.ParentId is null) order by post0_.CreatedAt desc]
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value
```

.

I'm using NHibernate v3 with POCO models and handcrafted SQL (using DBDeploy.NET to manage database versioning)

It's possible, and most likely, that I've made an error when converting the schema creation SQL from SQL Server to MySQL but what is perplexing me is I get this error even when a query results in no records.

Why is NHibernate trying to create any objects? What am I not understanding about how it works?

This is an example of one of the queries. This raised the exception when rows are returned. The only column that returns null, by design, is the Post.ParentId column.

```
return GetSession()
    .Query<Post>()
    .Where(p => p.CreatedBy.Username == username && p.Parent == null)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
    .Take(count)
    .ToList();
```

The map files and the classes haven't changed but have included them for reference below.

Would really welcome any thoughts I where I should be looking.

The Post map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="clubrd.service" namespace="clubrd.service">
  <class name="Post" table="Posts">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb"/>
    </id>
    <property name="CreatedAt"/>
    <property name="Title" column="Title"/>
    <property name="Body"/>
    <many-to-one name="CreatedBy" column="CreatedBy"/>
    <many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentId"/>
    <set name="Children">
      <key column="ParentId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Post"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The User map, referenced here as Post.CreatedBy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="clubrd.service" namespace="clubrd.service">
  <class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Username" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Email" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="PasswordHash"/>
    <property name="PasswordSalt"/>
    <one-to-one name="Profile" class="Profile" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Post class

```
public class Post : Entity
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The User class

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return this.Username; } }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**edit** Full output at error point plus the preceding NHibernate logs showing the entity being constructed.

```
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory:  2010-12-18 15:56:20,159 INFO Default entity-mode: Poco
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory:  2010-12-18 15:56:20,160 INFO Named query checking : enabled
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl:  2010-12-18 15:56:20,211 INFO building session factory
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory:  2010-12-18 15:56:20,580 INFO no name configured
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,389 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.Post (p) -> CreatedBy (Class)]
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,406 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.User () -> Username (Class)]
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,416 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.Post (p) -> CreatedBy (Class)]
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,417 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.User () -> Username (Class)]
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,419 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.Post (p) -> Parent (Class)]
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,424 INFO handling property dereference [clubrd.service.Post (p) -> CreatedAt (Class)]
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,564 WARN System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect.GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, Int32 offset, Int32 limit, Nullable`1 offsetParameterIndex, Nullable`1 limitParameterIndex) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Dialect\MySQLDialect.cs:line 197
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1119
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 399
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 236
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1665
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,576 ERROR Nullable object must have a value.
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,577 WARN System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect.GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, Int32 offset, Int32 limit, Nullable`1 offsetParameterIndex, Nullable`1 limitParameterIndex) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Dialect\MySQLDialect.cs:line 197
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1119
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 399
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 236
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1665
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter:  2010-12-18 15:56:21,579 ERROR Nullable object must have a value.

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not execute query
[ select post0_.Id as Id1_, post0_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_, post0_.Title as Title1_, post0_.Body as Body1_, post0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy1_, post0_.ParentId as ParentId1_ from Posts post0_, Users user1_ where post0_.CreatedBy=user1_.Id and ((user1_.Username is null) and (? is null) or user1_.Username=?) and (post0_.ParentId is null) order by post0_.CreatedAt desc ]
  Name:p1 - Value:username1
[SQL: select post0_.Id as Id1_, post0_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_, post0_.Title as Title1_, post0_.Body as Body1_, post0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy1_, post0_.ParentId as ParentId1_ from Posts post0_, Users user1_ where post0_.CreatedBy=user1_.Id and ((user1_.Username is null) and (? is null) or user1_.Username=?) and (post0_.ParentId is null) order by post0_.CreatedAt desc]
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value.
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs: line 1674
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs: line 1589
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs: line 1583
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Loader\QueryLoader.cs: line 298
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs: line 110
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLQueryPlan.cs: line 105
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs: line 658
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs: line 634
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionQueryImpl.cs: line 63
at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs: line 78
at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs: line 27
at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Linq\NhQueryProvider.cs: line 102
at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source)
at clubrd.data.Repository.PostRepository.UsersLatestPosts(String username, Int32 count) in PostRepository.cs: line 13
at clubrd.data.integrationtest.Repository.PostRepositoryTests.UsersPosts() in PostRepositoryTests.cs: line 103
--InvalidOperationException
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down, make the question a bit shorter? Also, please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: I'm struggling to narrow it down looking for pointers of where to start really. Have appended the full output. It seems odd to me that I get this error in another section of the application when there are no results returned from the query. If there's no instance, why is an assignment being attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mauricio for pointing me back at the stack trace. It seems to be an issue with the MySQL5Dialect implementation of GetLimitString(). Changing the dialect to MySQLDialect from MySQL5Dialect seems to resolve the issue.

Though, maybe I'm tired but when I look at the code the MySQL version seems to contain a risk of this exception and not the MySQL5 version.

**MySQLDialect**

```
public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, int offset, int limit, int? offsetParameterIndex, int? limitParameterIndex)
        {
            var pagingBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder();
            pagingBuilder.Add(querySqlString);
            pagingBuilder.Add(" limit ");

            if (offset > 0)
            {
                pagingBuilder.Add(Parameter.WithIndex(offsetParameterIndex.Value));
                pagingBuilder.Add(", ");
            }

            pagingBuilder.Add(Parameter.WithIndex(limitParameterIndex.Value));

            return pagingBuilder.ToSqlString();
        }
```

**MySQL5Dialect**

```
public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, int offset, int limit)
        {
            var pagingBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder();

            pagingBuilder.Add(querySqlString);
            pagingBuilder.Add(" limit ");
            if (offset > 0)
            {
                pagingBuilder.Add(offset.ToString());
                pagingBuilder.Add(", ");
            }

            pagingBuilder.Add(limit.ToString());

            return pagingBuilder.ToSqlString();
        }
```